# Getting User Email For Old Users On Yammer

Tags: yammer

I am trying to get historical data for all of our Yammer posts. We are very active, and like to look back sometimes. The data is loaded into a data warehouse.

For current messages, I get a list of users and then match messages against the user list. I can then use the email address as a unique identifier for the user (our users likes to change their names on the network to goofy names, or to someone else's name) to match it up with the rest of the user information we have for them.

The problem is that I when I start going back in time with the messages, the only information I get about a user is the ID and the username for users that are suspended or deleted. I can't seem to establish a way to match the username against a person. Some of the usernames contain periods (firstname.lastname), and other don't.

Is there any way to get the email address of the suspended/deleted user?

Comment: Why are you using the email address field as the primary key for your data warehouse? The persistent and unique identifier for a user account is the ID, not the email address.

Comment: @michaelh I'm not using the email as the PK, but I am using it to match my DW users to my Yammer users